# Exporting photo

Tags: export

I used the custom feature in the print area in lightroom.  I put three photos in one page. I want to know how to save my photo and export it to my desk top. I don’t want to print it using my printer.

When I tried to export it, I only exported one of the three photos.

Comment: Did you save your project, *close it so you are no longer working on it*, before you tried to export it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the "Print Job" panel you can select to "print to" printer, or JPEG file.

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks.

Comment: I use "print to PDF" all of the time with other applications. I'm not sure about LR because I haven't used it in years, but it *should* have such an option unless they're too cheap to pay Adobe the royalties to use it (LOL - it's a joke, since LR is an Adobe product).